# Ufw unable to forward outside port to port 22 unless I open port 22, which is defeating the purpose of port forwarding

Tags: ssh, ufw

I would like to remote ssh to my server from outside using a different port then 22 (this is just to add an additional level of security, since I have noticed numerous attempts daily to access my system on port 22)

I can configure port forwarding with ufw, but It is not working unless I enable port 22. This will actually defeat the purpose of the forwarding, since it opens port 22 to the outside.

Comment: Is your server directly on internet, or is there a router between your server and internet? If directly on internet you just need to have ufw allow the new ssh port, not forward it. Of course, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has to be changed as to `Port` to listen on. If you have a router, then your forwarding has to be done there.

Comment: Yes my server is  also the router. That is exactly what I have done. Enabled the additional port with ssh and blocked port 22 from the outside. This issues demonstrate the limitations of ufw. In my prior setup before I started using ufw. I did not need to enable the additional port with ssh. I was able to forward to port 22 without enabling it for the outside.